# Editar campos individualmente em janela modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Possuo uma lista de clientes que é exibida utilizando um `foreach`, onde é possível abrir individualmente uma janela modal. Contudo, ao editar um determinado campo para tal cliente, essa informação se repete para todos os outros. Gostaria de saber como faço para inserir informações especificas para cada cliente em seu respectivo modal [utilizando jQuery/JavaScript].

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", ".modalEditar", function () {
     var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-body #idCli").val( myBookId );
});
</script>

<?php foreach($resultado as $cli){
    $id     = $cli['id'];
    $nome       = $cli['nome'];
    ?>
    <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $nome; ?></td>
    <td><a class="modalEditar" data-id="<?php echo $id ;?>" data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#editar">Editar</a>
    </td>
    <?php } ?>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="editar" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="bx-modal">
                    <h4>Corpo
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="idCli" id="idCli" hidden value="" />
                <div class="spanN" style="margin-top:10px;">
                    <label>Texto de Correção:</label>
                </div>
                <textarea id="texto-correcao" name="texto-correcao"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" style="float:left;" class="btn btn-default 
fecharModal" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                <button type="button" id="enviarCartaCorrecao" style="float:right;" 
class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```